# styled-components not properly installing to react-native project

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-cli

I am trying to set up my first React-Native project and tried doing it first with Expo but ran into the same problem as with React-Native CLI when wanting to install styled-components.

The error I get is:

> Component Exception
> Invalid prop `color` supplied to `StyleSheet generated`: `red`
> Valid color formats are... (and a list of valid formats)

In expo I kept getting the same error but VSCode was showing an import error at the styled-components import saying that the styled-components has type any (even if I am doing a normal JS project not Typescript). At the beginning Expo was giving me the error that it can't find the styled-components folder in node_modules (even if it is properly installed).

This is the error the emulator throws at me: [Component Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ode7V.png)

I have tried to reinstall styled-components - reinstalling it with `npm install styled-components --save` and still getting the same error.

I have also tried importing the styled-components in different ways

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
```

and

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

I have also tried different ways of creating the styled component

```
const Title = styled.Text`
  color: 'red';
`;
```

and

```
const Title = styled(Text)`
  color: 'red';
`;
```

It is as if styled-components is not recognized and then the project is looking for the StyleSheet formatting... Have anybody experienced similar issues?

Comment: I think the problem is not how you installed the component, but how you're mapping the style itself. You just need to write `color: red;`

If you see the example they have in [styled-components website](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native) they have the color without the ''

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my problem.